# Why pickle dump size is larger than the original image dataset size?

Tags: python-3.x, image, numpy, pickle, image-preprocessing

The image dataset contains approximately **70,000** images. I tried to create 6 pickle files out of them. Therefore, each pickle dump file contains around **11519** pre-processed images. The image folder size on the disk is approximately **2.5G**. However, each pickle file is generated with a size of **6.45G**.

In total **6.45 * 6 = 38.7 G**!!

Is this the expected behavior or I am doing something wrong? I used the following script to generate pickle files.

```
import os
import pickle
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

n = 11519
images = []
DATADIR = r"path/to/images"

def data_preprocessing(samples, img_size):
    img_width, img_height, channels = img_size, img_size, 3
    image_list = [np.array((Image.open(os.path.join(DATADIR, filename)).convert('RGB')).resize((img_width, img_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)) for filename in samples]
    images = np.asarray(image_list).astype('float32') / 255.0
    ds_samples = np.reshape(images, (len(samples), img_width, img_height, channels))
    return ds_samples


def divide_chunks(samples, n): 
    # looping till length samples 
    for i in range(0, len(samples), n):  
        yield samples[i:i + n] 

# Appending files from directory to list
for file in (os.listdir(DATADIR)):
    images.append(file)

# Creating parts
sub_samples = list(divide_chunks(images, n)) 

# Saving pickle files
for chunk in range(len(sub_samples)):
  outfile = open("sample_{}.pkl".format(chunk), 'wb')
  pickle.dump(data_preprocessing(sub_samples[chunk], 224), outfile, protocol=4)
  outfile.close()
```

Comment: Serialized objects (via Pickle) are not the same as the original image files, most likely containing information regarding the libraries and versions you used to save them. In this particular case, numpy arrays will certainly use more disk space and transfer lots of informational you might not need in the future. Do you need to save the preprocessed images data as .pkl files, or could you use some alternative such as .csv or .txt?

Comment: You're taking the pictures (which were probably 16-bit color), converting them to RGB (24-bit color), converting each channel to 32-bit floats (96-bit color), and then subsampling them by overlapping windows.  Of course they're going to be huge!